# pH Curves for Titrations

Tags: ph, titration

Why does the pH rapidly increase near the equivalence point during--why does the slope of the graph of a pH curve sharply increase around this area?

Answer (score 6):

I'll try to answer your question firstly qualitatively, then quantitatively (using mathematical equation):

Let's consider the case of  the titration of strong acid (volume $V_a$ and concentration$C_a$: unknown) with a strong base (volume $V_b$ and concentration$C_b$), and we'll denote $V_b(eq)$ the volume of base at the equivalence:

1. The pH increases slowly at first because the pH scale is 
   logarithmic, which means that a pH of 1 will have 10 times the 
   hydronium ion concentration than a pH of 2. Thus, as the 
   hydronium ion is initally removed, it takes a lot of base to change 
   its concentration by a factor of 10, but as more and more 
   hydronium ion is removed, less base is required to change its 
   concentration by a factor of 10. Near the equivalence point, a 
   change of a factor of 10 occurs very quickly, which is why the 
   graph is extremely steep at this point. As the hydronium ion 
   concentration becomes very low, it will again take a lot of base to 
   increase the hydroxide ion concentration by 10 fold to change the 
   pH significantly.
2. Let's find the equation of the titration curve in the the region $0<V_b<V_b(eq)$:

The number of moles of $\ce{H3O+}$ before the titration is $C_aV_a$

The number of moles of $\ce{H3O+}$ after adding the volume   $V_b$ of the base is $C_aV_a-C_bV_b$

Then, the concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$ is $$[\ce{H3O+}]=\frac{C_aV_a-C_bV_b}{V_a+V_b}$$
So, the titration curve in the region $0<V_b<V_b(eq)$  $$p\mathrm{H}=-\log\frac{C_aV_a-C_bV_b}{V_a+V_b}$$
If you trace this mathematical function $p\mathrm{H}=f(V_b)$, you will have a smooth slope at the beginning and as $V_b \rightarrow V_b(eq)$, the slope of the graph sharply increases as the function becomes not defined: $C_aV_a=C_bV_b(eq)$.

Comment: A while back I made a more formal derivation in a [similar question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/8057/1499), at the expense of making it significantly harder to read. Perhaps the asker can also browse the answers there.

Comment: You're right, the answer given there is really nice. Thank you