# pH Curve in Acid/Base Titrations

Tags: acid-base, ph, titration

[image: Question]

So I came across a question on the equation of the pH curve, and I wanted to know how the user here arrived at the matter balance equation. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the question:

[The reason behind the steep rise in pH in the acid base titration curve](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8057/the-reason-behind-the-steep-rise-in-ph-in-the-acid-base-titration-curve/8074#8074)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nicolau already outlined it quite clearly in his answer.

> Notice that after mixing the solutions, the number of moles of species containing $\ce{A}$ ($\ce{HA}$ or $\ce{A−}$) is simply $n_A = C_A V_A$

so you have $n_{\ce{HA}} + n_{\ce{A-}} = C_A V_A$

> We will assume that volumes are additive (total volume $V_T = V_A + V_B$)

and given that $[\ce{HA}] = n_{\ce{HA}}/V_T$ and $[\ce{A-}] = n_{\ce{A-}}/V_T$ it should be fairly clear that

$$[\ce{HA}] + [\ce{A-}] = \frac{C_A V_A}{V_A + V_B}$$

as desired.